# ERROR URI must be a String or URInterface

Tags: php, mysqli, wordpress, api, uri

Espero que esten genial. Les comento mi problema:

Estoy haciendo un script en PHP (trabajando en wordpress) que, basandose en la ID del usuario, devuelve su nombre completo y este es buscado dentro de un objeto (que nos es devuelto por una API exterior) para asi poder imprimir sus propiedades en pantalla.

El codigo que devuelve la API es este:

```
<?php
function llamadaApi(){
        $url = "https://www.uesva.com/soap/ApiServiceHTTP.php?method=getPilotList&idVA=RTRR2gbvXXX";
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $jsonData = json_decode($content);
        return $jsonData;
    }
```

Este esta siendo llamado con require_once() dentro del archivo PHP que se encarga de la comparacion de datos. Presentado a continuacion: fdsp-user_data.php

```
<?php
require_once ("llamadaApi.php");
require_once ("/wp-load.php");

            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            // si el usuario esta logueado...
            $carlos =  get_current_user_id();
            // dame la ID del usuario que esta iniciando sesion y guardalo en $carlos
            $value = md5($carlos);
            //Hacemos de carlos un hash md5 para posterior uso en cookies (opcional depende como me levante)
            print_r($carlos);
              //para puro testing
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = $carlos";
            $get = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                if($get){
                    //obteniendo nombre del objeto para buscarlo dentro del API.
                    foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
                        $name = $value->display_name;
                        echo $name;
                    }
                    /****************************Mensaje de bienvenida******************/
                    echo '<div class="nombre_capitan">';
                    echo '<b id="casilla_capitan">¡Bienvenido Capitán ' . $name . '!';
                    echo '</b>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    /*******************************************************************/
                    
                    $almacen = llamadaApi();
                    foreach ($almacen as $valor) {
                        $millas_voladas = $valor->dataAirline->totalMilesFlown;
                    }
                    
                        echo '<div class="prueba">';
                        echo '<b id="sis">millas voladas: ' . $millas_voladas;
                        echo '</b>';
                        echo '</div>';
                }
            }
```

Y el problema que devuelve es:

> Error fatal - Error URI must be a string or URIInterface

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo solucionar esto? (La documentacion de PHP no me dice nada).

Y mi otra pregunta es: ¿Puedo ordenarle a mi bucle foreach que comience a buscar desde donde aparezca el valor de $name o algun valor X dentro de mi objeto?

Muchisimas gracias a todos por la ayuda que puedan brindar, se los aprecia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien! Lo acabo de resolver. El primer error era que estaba incluyendo el archivo `"wp-load.php"` de forma incorrecta.

La forma correcta es: `require_once __DIR__ . [ubicacion]`.
Y por ultimo tenia que declarar la variable global `$wpdb` (que es la que se encarga de las conexiones a la base de datos)

Entonces quedó asi:

```
<?php
... codigo de arriba
require_once __DIR__ . "/wp-load.php";
global $wpdb;
// sigue
```

Gracias a todos los que se pasaron de todas formas.